# std::thread and input with std::cin in an opengl application

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, io, stdthread

I use a thread in order to provide a shell to user, in an OpenGL application.

My problem is that I can't cancel the thread at the end of my mainloop, because std::thread doesn't provide a cancel method, and my thread is blocked with a `std::cin >> var` call, so I can't use a boolean to store the fact that the thread should stop.

I would like to know if there is a good way of using std::cin in a thread (std::thread), or alternative solutions.

Comment: is your thread detached or joined

Comment: None. If I call thread.join() the application will wait the end of the thread, but the thread is blocked with std::cin call. I may not understand what is detaching a thread (detaching of the current process as fork() does ?)

Comment: Sounds like it's joined, after making a thread in c++11 you either call join or detach on it

Comment: do you have to read using `>>`?  An asychronous io call might help (if not standardized).

Comment: Yes I use `>>` but I've found something: when I detach the thread in the constructor of the ThreadClass I wrote, i've problems; when I detach it in the mainloop, it works randomly: if the thread starts to be executed before beeing detached, it doesn't work, in the other case it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might want is an interrupting thread, c++ doesn't give you one but [c++ concurrency in action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988770) has a simple implementation of one. That might be what you need. Wouldn't be surprised if boost also has one since the book is written by the maintainer of the thread library.

```
class interrupt_flag
    {
    public:
    void set();
        bool is_set() const;
    };
    thread_local interrupt_flag this_thread_interrupt_flag;
    class interruptible_thread
    {
        std::thread internal_thread;
        interrupt_flag* flag;
    public:
        template<typename FunctionType>
        interruptible_thread(FunctionType f)
        {
            std::promise<interrupt_flag*> p;
            internal_thread=std::thread([f,&p]{
                ￼￼￼￼    p.set_value(&this_thread_interrupt_flag);
                    f(); 
                });
        flag=p.get_future().get();
    }
    ￼￼void interrupt()
    {
        if(flag) {
            flag->set();
        }
    ￼￼￼￼} 
};
```

Now you can easily cancel the thread from your main. I put a link to the book but all the code from the book is also online for free. Here is a link to the [source code](http://www.manning.com/williams/) in the book, though it may be hard to navigate without the book, which is a great read BTW.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It shows me that I need an instance in my thread, which will send the exception.

Comment: `internal_thread=std::thread([f,&p] ...` -> I need to send a "pointer targeting a pointer targeting a flag" to my thread, and the thread initialize the adress.

Comment: The flag cannot be read uninitialized because of the check that it's initialized, as for how would it help I have to admit that I didn't read it too thoroughly but had remembered I saw it in the book, I though all he needed to be able to do is interrupt the thread from main

Comment: @KerrekSB you know the impl may not be 100% complete now that i look at it

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant btw it looks like boost thread library has an interruptible thread so you may want to just use that as it is likely more complete

Comment: I've a strange result, I used the same sort of class as you wrote. Randomly, the program is blocked and waits user inputs (std::cin >> var), I restart it and then it's only the opengl part which is active and not the inputs (it's totally random). Does anyone know why this pb happens ?

Comment: I wrote `std::cin >> str;` in my code, sorry for the fault in my comment. But I don't know why it blocks the 2 threads. It seems to be that the thread is not created but execute the function in the mainloop sometimes.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant well at this point you should prolly just ask a new question or at least post some code, since I answered the first question

Comment: I've replaced std::thread by phtread because I don't have problems with it. I will ask a new question in few minutes. Thanks for your help.